# How to validate end date must greater than start date using drop down list

Tags: c#, javascript

I have two drop down lists.In the first drop down list i have start year and in the second drop down list i have end year.I have to validate end year must be greater than start year.I am using drop down list.Not input text boxes.And after validation i have to place validation messages right to the drop down list not alert boxes.
Provide me an sample or some code related to this

Thanks and Regards
Srinivas

Comment: You can use javascript for that purpose. Add "onchange" event to end_date's dropdown and validate there by parsing both dropdown's values.

Comment: Seems like another [`Give me dah codez` questions](http://whathaveyoutried.com)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with JavaScript then you can just compare the dates with simple if condition

```
var startDate = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
var endDate = document.getElementById("EndDate").value;

if ((Date.parse(startDate) <= Date.parse(endDate))) {
    alert("End date should be greater than Start date");
    document.getElementById("EndDate").value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working with ASP.Net you can use [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmpVal1" ControlToCompare="ddlStartDate" 
         ControlToValidate="ddlEndDate" Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual"   
         ErrorMessage="*Invalid Data" runat="server"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

try some thing like this.

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidatorDate" runat="server"
ControlToCompare="ddlDate1"
ControlToValidate="ddlDate2" Display="Dynamic"
ErrorMessage="date 2nd is must be grater than 1st "
Operator="LessThanEqual"
Type="Date" 
ValueToCompare="<%= ddlDate2.SelectedValue.ToShortString() %>"></asp:CompareValidator>
```